# Recursive Formula based on previous Row's Result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's consider the following query:

```sql
with
    init as (
        select 0.1 as y0
    ),
    cte as (
        select 1 as i, 1 as x   -- x_1
        union all
        select 2 as i, 10 as x  -- x_2
        union all 
        select 3 as i, 100 as x -- x_3
        order by i asc
    )
select cte.x, init.y0 -- <- ?
from cte
join init
    on true
```

There is a CTE `init` specifying an inital value y_0 and a CTE `cte` specifying rows with a value `x` and an index `i`.

My question is whether I can write a `select` which realizes the following simple, recursive formula.

`y_n+1 = y_n + x_n+1`

So, the result should be 3 rows with values: `1.1, 11.1, 111.1` (for `y_1, y_2, y_3`).

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> write a select which realizes the following simple, recursive formula.
> y_n+1 = y_n + x_n+1

Consider below

```
select x, y0 + sum(x) over(order by i) as y
from cte, init
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: the expected result you shown in your question - does not match the formula you provided - so obviously above output is different from one in your question :o)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the “OVER” statement. You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_over_clause) about the syntax.

```
with
    init as (
        select 0.1 as y0
    ),
    cte as (
        select 1 as ts, 1 as i, 1 as x   -- x_1
        union all
        select 2, 2, 10 as x  -- x_2
        union all 
        select 3, 3, 100 as x
        union all
        select 4, 4, 109 as x -- x_3
        union all
        select 5, 5, 149 as x 
        order by i asc
    )

SELECT *,init.y0 + SUM(i) OVER(
    ORDER BY (ts) 
  ) AS res
FROM cte join init
    on true
```